# How to sort two different models unrelated models in mongoose as one array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models in mongoose: User and Company.I want to get all users and companies as one array and sort them by created_at.
I have tried this code but it doesn't work.Any suggestions?

```
    const users = await Users.find();
    const companies = await Company.find();

    const result = [...users, ...companies].sort(el => el.created_at);
```

Comment: What's the format of the `created_at` field ? Is it a string or a date ?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" actually mean?  Does it throw an exception?